# New Mac Pro architecture: Will audio software run well on this out the gate?

Tags: osx

I'm in need of a new system and I'd like to wait it out for the new Mac Pros.  Can anyone tell from the specs whether audio software will have to adapt significantly and be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone tell from the specs whether
>   audio software will have to adapt
>   significantly and be updated?

Not because of the hardware. Although I don't know about Pro Tools which breaks at times when it shouldn't. There's likely an operating system upgrade to bring in the new device drivers and firmware, but they shouldn't cause problems to top-level software. Sometimes things break temporarily e.g. if an I/O chip e.g. FireWire gets changed and peripheral device manufacturers need to upgrade their software to reflect the changes.

Nothing exceptional or surprising is expected though. It's Apple's (or any manufacturer's) job to handle upgrades so that they don't cause problems to their customers.